# XSLT , search large document inside For Loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a large xml file with more than 20k records.Here is the example of xml file.
I need to loop through each Employee record ( in this case it is <wd:Report_Entry>) and read it's content.

Each Employee record has it's Manager "Employee_ID". Using Manager's "Employee_ID", I need to to find Manager email address.

I am able to do it using below code but it's talking lot of time. Can some one please suggest if there is any other way to achieve this ?

Here is my xslt Template :

```css
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:Root>
      <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:Report_Data/ns0:Report_Entry">
        <tns:Record>
          <tns:FirstName>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Legal_First_Name"/>
          </tns:FirstName>
          <xsl:variable name="Manager_Emp_Id" select="ns0:Manager_Level_01/ns0:ID[@ns0:type='Employee_ID']"/>
          <tns:ManagerEmail>
            <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:Report_Data/ns0:Report_Entry[ns0:Employee_ID=$Manager_Emp_Id]/ns0:Emails_group/ns0:Email_Address"/>
          </tns:ManagerEmail>
        </tns:Record>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tns:Root>
  </xsl:template>
```

Here is my xslt Template :
Here is the sample xml file :

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Report_Data xmlns:wd="deltacore.com" xmlns="deltacore.com">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:User_Name>EM11</wd:User_Name>
    <wd:Employee_ID>1111</wd:Employee_ID>
    <wd:Legal_First_Name>John</wd:Legal_First_Name>
    <wd:Legal_Last_Name>William</wd:Legal_Last_Name>
    <wd:Legal_Name_in_General_Display_Format>John William</wd:Legal_Name_in_General_Display_Format>
    <wd:Legal_Name_in_Reporting_Display_Format>William, John</wd:Legal_Name_in_Reporting_Display_Format>
    <wd:Full_Legal_Name>John William</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
    <wd:Preferred_First_Name>John</wd:Preferred_First_Name>
    <wd:Preferred_Last_Name>William</wd:Preferred_Last_Name>
    <wd:Preferred_Name_group/>
    <wd:Preferred_Name_in_General_Display_Format>John William</wd:Preferred_Name_in_General_Display_Format>
    <wd:Preferred_Name_in_Reporting_Display_Format>William, John</wd:Preferred_Name_in_Reporting_Display_Format>
    <wd:Emails_group>
      <wd:Email_Usage_Type wd:Descriptor="Work">
        <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Type_ID">WORK</wd:ID>
      </wd:Email_Usage_Type>
      <wd:Email_Visibility wd:Descriptor="Public">
        <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Access_ID">PUBLIC</wd:ID>
      </wd:Email_Visibility>
      <wd:Is_Primary>1</wd:Is_Primary>
      <wd:Email_Address>John.William@deltacore.com</wd:Email_Address>
    </wd:Emails_group>
 
    <wd:Manager_Level_01 wd:Descriptor="Peter Samual">
      <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">2222</wd:ID>
    </wd:Manager_Level_01>
    <wd:Manager_-_Level_01_group>
      <wd:Manager_Employee_ID>2222</wd:Manager_Employee_ID>
      <wd:Manager_Full_Legal_Name>Peter Samual</wd:Manager_Full_Legal_Name>
    </wd:Manager_-_Level_01_group>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  
  
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:User_Name>TM222</wd:User_Name>
    <wd:Employee_ID>2222</wd:Employee_ID>
    <wd:Legal_First_Name>Peter</wd:Legal_First_Name>
    <wd:Legal_Last_Name>Samual</wd:Legal_Last_Name>
    <wd:Legal_Name_in_General_Display_Format>Peter Samual</wd:Legal_Name_in_General_Display_Format>
    <wd:Legal_Name_in_Reporting_Display_Format>Samual, Peter</wd:Legal_Name_in_Reporting_Display_Format>
    <wd:Full_Legal_Name>Peter Samual</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
    <wd:Preferred_First_Name>Peter</wd:Preferred_First_Name>
    <wd:Preferred_Last_Name>Samual</wd:Preferred_Last_Name>
    <wd:Preferred_Name_group/>
    <wd:Preferred_Name_in_General_Display_Format>Peter Samual</wd:Preferred_Name_in_General_Display_Format>
    <wd:Preferred_Name_in_Reporting_Display_Format>Samual, Peter</wd:Preferred_Name_in_Reporting_Display_Format>
    <wd:Gender wd:Descriptor="Male">
      <wd:ID wd:type="Gender_Code">Male</wd:ID>
    </wd:Gender>
    <wd:Emails_group>
      <wd:Email_Usage_Type wd:Descriptor="Work">
        <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Type_ID">WORK</wd:ID>
      </wd:Email_Usage_Type>
      <wd:Email_Visibility wd:Descriptor="Public">
        <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Access_ID">PUBLIC</wd:ID>
      </wd:Email_Visibility>
      <wd:Is_Primary>1</wd:Is_Primary>
      <wd:Email_Address>John.Samual@deltacore.com</wd:Email_Address>
    </wd:Emails_group>
    <wd:Manager_Level_01 wd:Descriptor="Test Manager">
      <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">3333</wd:ID>
    </wd:Manager_Level_01>
    <wd:Manager_-_Level_01_group>
      <wd:Manager_Employee_ID>3333</wd:Manager_Employee_ID>
      <wd:Manager_Full_Legal_Name>Test Manager</wd:Manager_Full_Legal_Name>
    </wd:Manager_-_Level_01_group>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a key

```
       <xsl:key name="id" match="wd:Report_Entry" use="ns0:Employee_ID"/>
```

as a top-level element (i.e. child of `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform`), then use e.g.

```
      <tns:ManagerEmail>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('id', $Manager_Emp_Id)/ns0:Emails_group/ns0:Email_Address"/>
      </tns:ManagerEmail>
```

for the cross-reference.

Comment: @ MaritinHonnen forgot to highlight the reason why since good XSLT processors can implement `xsl:key` using hash tables for efficient document indexing. He even forgot to show implementation of his solution on his own maintained website. Consider my translation: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6Y.